# Workflows Always Remain In Progress

Tags: 2010, workflow

I have a custom workflow that was created in VS.  This workflow runs like it should about 50% of the time.  I am researching/debugging to make it run right 100% of the time and I noticed in Site Administration -> Workflows the following:

- Status: Active
- Associations: 1
- In Progress: 293

This is on a development environment so I know that there should not be more than a handful of workflows running at one time. It seems as though even though the workflow finishes its work, it never comes out of In Progress.

Is this normal behavior or is out system getting bogged down by workflows getting left in In Progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the workflow, how do you have the workflow configured to start? do you have an action telling the workflow to stop after the given function is completed?

You can also include an action within the workflow to change the status of the current item to completed when a given function is completed. If you have SharePoint designer, look at the action commands. If you have already done so, please disregard.

Comment: Since asking this question I have figured out my answer. "Do you have an action telling the workflow to stop after the given function is completed?" eluded to the answer. The answer is yes, this is normal behavior and the workflow must reach a final state to enter the Completed workflow state.